# how to reverse the parsing stored String from Database into HTML Tag understood by Browser?

Tags: c#, html, razor

i saved artikel in ordered list in the database , i want to get this stored string back as HTML tag , so as i saved it .. so that when i call the artikel from the database will be formed automatically in the Browser.

```
// index.cshtml

    @model ArtikelsViewModels

    @if (Model.Id == 1003)
    {

        <h1>Common myths about DI</h1>
        <p>
            @Model.Artikel
        </p>

    }

// Artikel like that  in the database is saved : 

<ul>
<li>Di is only revleant for late binding.</li> 
<li>Di is only revleant for unit testing.</li>
<li>Di is asort of abstract factory on steroids.</li>
<li>Di requiers a DI container</li>
<ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Html.Raw(@Model.Artikel)

However, in my honest opinion that may not be a secure way, as it could be prone to XSS.

Comment: I have used for XSS , i don't know if it is enough the attribue [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] plus it's PostHttp Method to hide the given parameters in the url , anyway thanks for your help it works .